# Pandoc Markdown: How to create overprint environments for beamer

Tags: beamer, pandoc

I am creating slides in markdown that I want to process using pandoc and beamer.  I wonder if there is a markdown way of creating an overprint environment?

I tried to do it with the fenced div extension, but it does not work:

```
---
title: 'Title'
author: Autor
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 3
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: true
---

# Trouble Shooting

## {}

### One slide

::: {.overprint}
\onslide<1>
Some text
\onslide<2>
Some alternative text
:::
```

In the .tex-file, the "overprint" is simply ignored.

**Note**: I am looking for an answer that works with "plain pandoc" and does not use extra filters.

Comment: You need to use a filter to use fenced divs. Try: https://github.com/chdemko/pandoc-latex-environment

Comment: Thanks! According to https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html, fenced divs are activated by default, so they should be read by pandoc. But you say that the divs do not get written without a filter?

Comment: @DG The filter looks interesting.  Unfortunately, I need a way that works without filters, since I want to share my markdown with other people (without telling them to install additional filters etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One was that works is to use the extension `raw_attribute` (https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html):

````
```{=beamer}
\begin{overprint}
```

\onslide<1>
Some text
\onslide<2>
Some alternative text

```{=beamer}
\end{overprint}
```
````

Not pretty, but it works.